# Dynamically add listeners to buttons

Tags: android, button, android-intent

In my `Activity` I have 50 buttons, and at the click of every button I would like to launch the same `Activity`.

I would like to avoid setting the listeners and intents for each button. 
Is there a trick to do this?

This is the listener I use for only one `Button`:

```
uno = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button07);
        uno.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent activityChangeIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Interno.class);

                    MainActivity.this.startActivity(activityChangeIntent);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Do you want all 50 to fire the *exact* same `Intent`? If so, why? If they all need to have different data/extras attached, that's possible, but I don't see that from your code sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add

```
<Button
...
android:onClick="onClick" />
```

on your XML layout, for every button. And have a method in your class

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
}
```

Comment: Also possible ;) nice!

Answer (score 0):

```
Button[] buttons = new Button[SIZE];
for(int i=0; i<some_value; i++) {    
    String buttonID = "btn" + i ;  //THE ID OF YOUR BUTTON
    int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(buttonID, "id", "com.sample.project");  //PLEASE CHANGE WITH YOUR PROJECT NAMESPACE
    buttons[i] = ((Button) findViewById(resID));
    buttons[i].setOnClickListener(this);      
}
```

You could just loop over your buttons, find them by string name and add a listener. Here the buttons are stored in a array...

Answer (score 0):

On every button object in xml file add a property like this:

```
<Button android:onClick="clickMe" />
```

now add this method into `Activity.java` block :

```
public void clickMe(View v){
  //TODO something
}
```

Good Luck.